# Crop Raster from using Polygon shapefile in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, clip

I am trying to crop a raster by a polygon in R to the state of Sergipe-Brazil. My raster is a raster brick criated by 7 .tif files which are EVI (vegetation index) time series. Since the EVI archives are larger then the state I want, I'm trying to crop it by using a Polygon shapefile of Sergipe. Here is the script:

---

```
# Loading the packages
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(RCurl)
library(bitops)
library(hddtools)
library(XML)
library(zoo)

# Creating the rasterbrick
evi <- list.files(pattern = '^.*\\.tif$')
evistack <- stack(evi)
evibrick <- brick(evistack)

# Converting from -1 to 1 (EVI)
evit1<-evibrick/10000

#Saving the RASTER BRICK
writeRaster(evit1, filename="evi_2000t1.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

# Importing the shapefile of Sergipe
se <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/ArquivosR/EVI/Dados_anuais/2000", layer = "Estado")

### Transforming the CRS os the shapefile
SE.utm <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(se)), "1")))
proj4string(SE.utm) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=24 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
SE.utm@bbox; SE.utm@proj4string

### CRS GEO (GeoTiff)
SE.geo<- spTransform(SE.utm, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
SE.geo@bbox; SE.geo@proj4string

# Reprojecting the RasterLayer
projection(evit1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
alt.utm <- projectRaster(evit1, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

### Cropping
evit1.crop <- crop(alt.utm, extent(SE.geo), snap='out')
image(evit1.crop, asp=1)
```

I've changed the CRS os the shapefile to let both rasterbrick and shapefile in the same coordinate system. BUT, when I run it:

```
cr <- crop(alt.utm, extent(SE.geo), snap="out")

Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

Checking out the extent of the files I got this:

```
extent(alt.utm)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -38.24549 
xmax        : -36.39112 
ymin        : -11.56996 
ymax        : -9.51354 

extent(SE.geo)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -37.44375
xmax        : -37.44375 
ymin        : -10.58074 
ymax        : -10.58074
```

I'll aprecciate any help!

Comment: SE.geo looks degenerate: its xmin = xmax and ymin = ymax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a single point in the shapefile you are trying to crop to *and* the error message isn't exactly right. Lets' try and simulate that with a reproducible example:

```
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
p=data.frame(x=50,y=35) # a point in the middle of b
coordinates(p)=~x+y
```

Then:

```
> extent(b)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 0 
xmax        : 101 
ymin        : 0 
ymax        : 77 
> extent(p)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 50 
xmax        : 50 
ymin        : 35 
ymax        : 35 
> crop(b, extent(p), snap="out")
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

Perhaps the crop algorithm is computing the area of overlap, getting zero, and assuming the areas don't overlap. Anyway, its a minor bug in `crop`, I'd say. To check, lets just make sure it works with a larger extent:

```
> p2=data.frame(x=c(50,51),y=c(35,38))
> coordinates(p2)=~x+y
> crop(b, extent(p2), snap="out")
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 3, 1, 3, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 50, 51, 35, 38  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : red, green, blue 
min values  : 155,   165,  222 
max values  : 157,   168,  224
```

Of course we can't be sure this is your situation without your data, but it looks like it. Track back your `SE.geo` object and see what the original is like:

```
se <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/ArquivosR/EVI/Dados_anuais/2000", layer = "Estado")
```